# Accessing 'this' context in iffe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say i have a javascript class with a method, foo(). In another method, f.e componentDidMount, i want to access method foo() inside an iffe. How do i bind the 'this' context to be available inside the iffe?

I know i can this = self and use that, or use arrow syntax, but i would like to expand my knowledge of js & this, and thus do it with a proper binding. I've tried:

```
(function doSomething() {
  this.foo();
}.bind(this)())
```

But that doesn't work. Example code:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {}

  public componentDidMount() {
    (function doSomething() {
      this.foo();
    })();
  }

  foo() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: @Seblor please read the question. "*I know i can use arrow syntax*, but i would like to expand my knowledge of js & this, and thus do it with a proper binding."

Comment: [Your first snippet works](https://codesandbox.io/s/x510l04jq).

Comment: ..dang you are right. Tslint complaining is the problem here, not the actual code. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to use arrow functions, you can do the binding of your function to the outside context manually:

```
(function doSomething() {
  this.foo();
}.bind(this))();
```

The logic behind `this` keyword in javascript is discussed in detail in this question: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) Or in this amazing book by Kyle Simpson: [YDKJS: this & object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)

Answer (score 0):

Common pattern with iife is to use function arguments

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {}

  public componentDidMount() {
    (function doSomething(self) {
      self.foo();
    })(this);
  }

  foo() {
    // ...
  }
}
```